# Can a bathroom outlet be wired to a GFCI in another bathroom

Tags: gfci

I live in a fairly new, less than 10 year old, rental complex.

The outlet in one bathroom is not a GFCI, but is wired to a GFCI in another bathroom -- the two bathrooms do not share a wall.

Is that legal?

Also in kitchen, two GFCI outlets are wired to each other, such that if one on left trips, the one on right also stops working.  Is this legal?

Comment: Does the outlet in the 2nd bathroom turn off when the GFCI in the first bathroom trip? Also, is there anything else wired to that circuit?

Comment: The kitchen is legal it is a waste to have 2 on 1 circuit but legal. The bathrooms can be protected by 1 GFCI. Code dosent say where the GFCI is to be located.

Comment: The guest bathroom in my house is wired to the GFCI in the master bath. It's legal, but I don't like it. Two hair dryers being used at the same time would trip the breaker in fairly short order.

Comment: Yes 2nd bathroom trips with first bathroom is turned off.  Neither lights or fan in either bathroom is wired to the first bathroom GFCI.

Comment: Thank for the clarification.  I was planning on calling the building inspector if it was illegal as the complex has been crappy to deal with (and certainly crappy for a higher-priced 'luxury rental').  It does suck though cause the kitchen ones trip very easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a GFCI receptacle protect other receptacles?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51495/can-a-gfci-receptacle-protect-other-receptacles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the National Electrical Code

> **210.11(C)(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits.** In addition to the number of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at least one 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided to supply bathroom receptacle outlet(s). Such circuits shall have no other outlets.
>
> *Exception: Where the 20-ampere circuit supplies a single bathroom, outlets for other equipment within the same bathroom shall be permitted to be supplied in accordance with 210.23(A)(1) and (A)(2).*

So, you can supply multiple bathrooms with this circuit as long as it has no other equipment or outlets on the circuit except receptacles.

The kitchen receptacle fed downstream off of another GFCI receptacle is a waste of a good GFCI as Ed Beal said but is not a violation of the code.