# Can a GFCI be used as a disconnect?

Tags: wiring

New garage; the garage door lights go on every time you cross the beam, the outlets that power up the garage door lights are GFCI protected. Can I use the test button as a disconnect during the daytime hours on a daily basis?

Comment: Are they labeled "TEST/RESET" or "ON/OFF"?  Is this a breaker, deadfront, or receptacle type GFCI?

Comment: As a disconnect or a way to turn power off to the opener? Just to turn the power off it would work If a true disconnect is needed the GFCI would need to be listed for that what is the brand model?

Comment: This is a TEST/RESET receptacle type GFCI, I believe Leviton may sell a  type of GFCI  receptacle that has a switch incorporated in the upper part of it. It has to be 20 amp. I believe everything in a garage is suppose to be GFCI protected. Does a GFCI receptacle protect a light if it does not have a ground wire?

Answer (score 3):

### A GFCI needs to be *labeled* as a disconnecting means to be used as one

A normal receptacle or deadfront GFCI is not labeled or listed for disconnecting use -- it won't kill you for abusing it that way, but it could lead to some premature wear on the GFCI's contacts, shortening its lifespan.

There [are](http://www.leviton.com/en/products/gfrbf-w) deadfront GFCIs that are listed and labeled for this task, but they are uncommon, and will have "ON" and "OFF" labeled on/near the buttons in addition to "RESET" and "TEST", as depicted below:

[image: Leviton GFRBF-W]

### GFCI *breakers* are a different story though

However, a breaker-type GFCI is also a perfectly cromulent circuit breaker, and thus is considered a *disconnecting means* under the NEC even if it is not listed/labeled for SWD (Switching Duty) service.  (I know of no circumstance under the NEC where an appropriately rated circuit breaker, whether SWD listed/labeled or not, is not a legal disconnecting means.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the GFCI is designed for that use, and listed for that use.  I was forced to [amend this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/121240/47125) when I discovered one that actually was!